# How to assign same value or nan for many variables at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to assign same value to many variables. In this case, value is nan. My code is given below:

```
Pmpp_inIV=np.nan
ff=np.nan
Voc_inIV=np.nan
Voc_error=np.nan
i_at_voc=np.nan
Isc_inIV=np.nan
Isc_error=np.nan
v_at_Isc=np.nan
print(type(Pmpp_inIV))
print(Pmpp_inIV,ff,Voc_inIV,Voc_error,i_at_voc,Isc_inIV,Isc_error,v_at_Isc)
```

The output is:

```
<class 'float'>
nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

I would like to know better approach than this. I mean, instead of typing many `np.nan` those many times as variables, is there a better approach where it is written one time only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `dictionary`:

```
vals = ['Pmpp_inIV','ff','Voc_inIV','Voc_error','i_at_voc','Isc_inIV','Isc_error','v_at_Isc']

d = dict.fromkeys(vals, np.nan)
print (d)

{'Pmpp_inIV': nan, 'ff': nan, 'Voc_inIV': nan, 'Voc_error': nan, 
 'i_at_voc': nan, 'Isc_inIV': nan, 'Isc_error': nan, 'v_at_Isc': nan}
```

And select values by keys:

```
print (d['Pmpp_inIV'])
nan
```

But if need to create `DataFrame` with columns specified in `vals`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(10, columns=vals, index=np.arange(10))
print (df)
   Pmpp_inIV  ff  Voc_inIV  Voc_error  i_at_voc  Isc_inIV  Isc_error  v_at_Isc
0         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
1         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
2         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
3         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
4         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
5         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
6         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
7         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
8         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
9         10  10        10         10        10        10         10        10
```

Comment: thanks for nice answer. Good to see you answer my question. I hope! you remembered me while I tried to seek your help long ago to answer my Python questions.

Comment: I executed your first code. When I executed `print(Pmpp_inIV)`, it gives error as `NameError: name 'Pmpp_inIV' is not defined`. Help?

Comment: @Msquare - You forget for `d` like `print(d['Pmpp_inIV'])`

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it sounds strange to have to set a bunch of variables to NaN to start with, presumably just to mutate later on. I'm betting there's a much better way to do what you are trying to accomplish.

That said, you could also use `repeat` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import repeat

Pmpp_inIV, ff, Voc_inIV, Voc_error, \
    i_at_voc, Isc_inIV, Isc_error, v_at_Isc \
        = repeat(np.nan, 8)
```

Or you could set them dynamically using `locals()`

```
for k in ['Pmpp_inIV', 'ff', 'Voc_inIV', 'Voc_error',
          'i_at_voc', 'Isc_inIV', 'Isc_error', 'v_at_Isc']:
    locals()[k] = np.nan
```

Both of those solutions aren't great for maintenance, so I suggest considering a different approach altogether.